# В кой-то веки или В кои-то веки

Tags: орфоэпия, словосочетания

Является ли ошибкой написание «в кой-то веки», а не «в кои-то веки»? Я заметила, что в разговорной речи многие меняют «и» на «й», вроде как для комичного эффекта, не знаю… а на одном из форумов так вообще кто-то сказал, что есть выражение «в койтовеке» (???) — попасть в сложную или затруднительную ситуацию. 
Так что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка:
[**в кои-то веки**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/953/%D0%92), *разг. экспрес.*
1. Очень редко. [Дудукин:] *В кои-то веки дождались такого счастья, что видим вас в нашем обществе* (А. Островский. Без вины виноватые).
2. *Устар.* Когда-то, давно. *Ведь и я, душа моя, в кои-то веки слыл забиякой* (Тургенев. Бретёр).

**Кои-** — приставка, родственная «кое-» (она чаще употребляется в современном русском языке). Из-за этого и происходит путаница. «Кои» представляет собой устаревшее местоимение множественного числа (от местоимения «кой», употребляемого в значении «который»; аналогично «коя», «кое»).
Вариации таких слов сохранились и стали довольно употребимыми. Вот типичный пример использования устаревших местоимений — **ни в коей мере, ни коем случае.**

Частица **-то** — усилительная, в данном случае пишется через дефис (как и другие в составе наречий и неопределенных местоимений: -либо, -нибудь).
Иногда данное устойчивое выражение встречается без частицы и выглядит так: **в кои веки**.

**Веки** — это устаревшая форма множественного числа слова «век» (она употребляется только в устойчивых оборотах).

[В кои-то веки](https://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/153/%D0%92_%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%98-%D0%A2%D0%9E_%D0%92%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%98) или [в кои веки](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/13406/%D0%B2) (без частицы) — только так правильно.